# Expanding / Collapsing text area problems

Tags: javascript, jquery, textarea

I am trying to create an expandable text area that collapses back to its original height only if the box is empty.  If it is not empty, then I want the text area to stay expanded and to grow as needed (that is, to grow when the user inputs more text).  The text area should never hide the text that is entered--that is, it should never collapse to a height that hides any of its contents.

I put what I have so far in a fiddle at

http://jsfiddle.net/np5y4esr/8/

It's almost right but not quite.  If you enter enough text in the first `textarea` to make it expand beyond the 300px height, then click into the second `textarea` and then back into the first, the first will collapse on you. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

My rules are only those in the first paragraph above. If anyone can create a new fiddle to achieve this or modify mine to make it work, I would appreciate your help.

Edit: Is it posible to set a maximum expansion height for the text area?  That is, so that it expands as the user types but stops at a certain point (e.g. 400px) at which it just scrolls like the default text area behavior?

Comment: You can check `<textarea>` height before animation: `$('textarea.expand').focus(function () { if ($(this).height() < 100) { $(this).animate({ height: "100px" }, 300); } });` [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/np5y4esr/9/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to modify `'focus'` method like this :

```
$('textarea.expand').focus(function () {
    if($(this).val()==="" || $(this).height() < 100) {
         $(this).animate({ height: "100px" }, 300); 
    }

});
```

May it will help you.